# Data table - limit the output

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, primefaces

I have implemented the primefaces [data table](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf)
However, when I have to much data in my table it looks like that:

[image]

What are possible solutions to limit the cell size?

Comment: `word-wrap:break-word;` or `text-overflow:ellipsis;` CSS rules can fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to trim content and on each mouse hover, user will see all content:
Header in UI page(xhtml,...):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var iLimitTextSize = 20;
        trimtext();
    </script>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function trimtext(){  
        $(document).ready(function () {                  
            $(".ui-dt-c").each(function () {                            
                if ($.trim($(this).text()).length > iLimitTextSize) {
                    $(this).attr("title",$.trim($(this).text()));
                    $(this).text($.trim($(this).text()).substring(0, iLimitTextSize));
                    $(this).html($(this).html() + '...');
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

If you have component that execute its behavior and then update datatable, you need to call trimtext() function again, for example:

```
<p:commandButton value="Ok" update="datatable" oncomplete="trimtext();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`p:column` supports attributes `width` (size in pixels or percentage) and `style` (CSS styles).